# What are the B737 MAX 8's OEW and max payload?

Tags: boeing-737, weight, payload

I have Googled it, but have not found official info on that.

Answer (score 2):

The [type certificate of the Boeing 737](https://www.easa.europa.eu/sites/default/files/dfu/EASA%20TCDS%20IM%20A%20120%20-%20rev%2016%20final.pdf) provides the following table for the MAX:

[image: Table with MTRW, MTOW, MLW and ZFW from type B737 certificate]

Comment: Thanks, @DeltaLima

Answer (score 1):

[Wikipedia gives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_737_MAX#Specifications) 45,070 kg as the MAX 8's OEW and 20,882 kg as its maximum payload.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In fact, I'm looking for oficial information. I did some math and the 737 max 8 has greater OEW than 737-800 NG. That might not be an error, but I have to check. Regards, Evandro

Comment: @Evandrojs it would make sense with bigger, heavier engines.

Comment: For sure, @fooot. But even so, it is expected weight reduction on airframe with more composites.

Comment: @Evandrojs the MAX didn't add a lot of new composites, besides the engines the only major structural changes were the improved winglets and area around the APU.

Comment: Thank you, @fooot. The weight increase looks more reasonable now.

Answer (score 1):

I have found on Jane's database 45.065kg for OEW. And MZFW is 65.950kg. Doing the math, one get 20.885kg. So, Wikipedia info is quite good.